# Issue change JButton text repeatedly from within ActionPerformed method

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, action, dice

So I am relatively new to java (self taught so i would love any advice/criticism you could give) and as practice i decided to create a dice rolling program with swing using Jbuttons as Dice. To simulate the rolling of dice I wanted to randomly change the text of the Jbutton to different numbers for a few seconds before presenting the result.

The method I wrote to do this seemed to work until I tried to called if from within the ActionPerformed method. When I did this the program would freeze until the end of the method and then change the buttons text to the final result.

I was curious if someone could explain why this happens, or teach me the correct way do something like this. Thanks for any help.

Bellow is a quick example of the same issue

```
    package experiments.changingtext;

    import java.awt.GridLayout;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import javax.swing.*;

    public class ChangingText extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    JButton button = new JButton("Change Me");

    public ChangingText(){

        this.setSize(200,200);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel pane = new JPanel();

        button.addActionListener(this);
        pane.add(button);

        this.add(pane);

        this.setVisible(true);

        try{Thread.sleep(500);}catch(Exception ex){}
        //Works as expected
        this.changeButtonText();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        //when run program freezes and presents the final text "change to 5"
        if(e.getSource() == button){
            button.setText("change to 1");
            try{Thread.sleep(500);}catch(Exception ex){}

            button.setText("change to 2");
            try{Thread.sleep(500);}catch(Exception ex){}

            button.setText("change to 3");
            try{Thread.sleep(500);}catch(Exception ex){}

            button.setText("change to 4");
            try{Thread.sleep(500);}catch(Exception ex){}

            button.setText("change to 5");
        }
    }

    public void changeButtonText(){

        button.setText("change to 1");
            try{Thread.sleep(500);}catch(Exception ex){}

            button.setText("change to 2");
            try{Thread.sleep(500);}catch(Exception ex){}

            button.setText("change to 3");
            try{Thread.sleep(500);}catch(Exception ex){}

            button.setText("change to 4");
            try{Thread.sleep(500);}catch(Exception ex){}

            button.setText("change to 5");
    }
}
```

Comment: Swing uses a single thread to manage events and painting, this means we you use Thread.sleep, you're blocking the event dispatching thread, preventing it from painting the ui. Instead you could to use a Swing Timer

Answer (score 3):

There's no need to use background threads directly. Rather use a Swing Timer which does the background counting for you, and most importantly, allows all the intermittent calls to be made on the Swing event thread. Please check out the [Swing Timer Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more on how to use this very useful tool. Briefly, you create a new Timer within the JButton's ActionListener, give the Timer its own ActionListener which holds code that it calls repeatedly until done.

For example:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.EnumMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.*;

public class ChangingText2 extends JPanel {
    private static final int PREF_W = 400;
    private static final int PREF_H = PREF_W;
    private static final float PTS = 24f;
    public static final int TIMER_DELAY = 200;
    public static final int MAX_TIME = 2000;
    private JButton button = new JButton("1");

    public ChangingText2() {
        button.setFont(button.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD, PTS));
        button.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());

        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        add(button);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
            return super.getPreferredSize();
        }
        return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
    }

    private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {

        private Timer timer;

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (timer != null && timer.isRunning()) {
                return;
            }
            timer = new Timer(TIMER_DELAY, new ActionListener() {
                private int count = 0;

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e2) {
                    if (count * TIMER_DELAY > MAX_TIME) {
                        ((Timer) e2.getSource()).stop();
                        return;
                    }
                    count++;
                    Die die = Die.getRandomDie();
                    ((AbstractButton) e.getSource()).setText("" + die.getValue());
                }
            });
            timer.start();
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        ChangingText2 mainPanel = new ChangingText2();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("ChangingText2");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGui();
            }
        });
    }
}

enum Die {
    ONE(1), TWO(2), THREE(3), FOUR(4), FIVE(5), SIX(6);
    private int value;
    private static Random random = new Random();

    private Die(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public static Die getRandomDie() {
        int index = random.nextInt(Die.values().length);
        return Die.values()[index];
    }

}
```